# Windows 10 needs monitors on always

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Since I started using Display Port, Windows is intolerant of me turning off the displays. It thinks it's been taken away never to return or something, and scrambles all my window locations to sbrink them and arrange on the main screen.

This was seen on Win7 and now on Win10.

For some reason it won't shut down monitors as a idle-time thing. Locking leaves the Windows screen on the center monitor and the others are black but still on.

This machine won't sleep, either. When just booted and not logged init will sleep, but that's bad because upon waking it won't respond to mouse or keyboard and I have to use the reset button.  Telling it to sleep or hybernate explicitly does't do good things,in part because it doesn't wait for the raid card to wake up.

So I'm not interested in making it sleep or hybernate. Just to shut off the monitors.  I don't mind turning them off manually, if only Windows would tolerate it!

I have an NVidia 970 video card.

Any suggestions on how I can turn off monitors without Windows knowing or caring?

Comment: Driver version?

Comment: Latest, up-to-date. I can check later but it's always had that issue and other computers with display port or hdmi also react to monitors being turned off.

Comment: My system with the same card and Windows 10 doesn't

Comment: as far as I knew, every windows system will scramble all your windows if you turn off your display in a multi-monitor setup. It is very aggravating

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue. Can't quite follow your question enough to know if it's the exact same issue, but see if it works for you none the less.

What I wound up doing is setting the power button action to turn off displays. That way, when you press the power button, it keeps the computer running, but allows the monitors to go into standby. This isn't exactly off, but if your goal is just to preserve the back light or remove the distracting display, this is perfectly fine. Instructions on how to do this:

1) Search for "power options" in start, and select the first result

2) Click "change plan settings" next to the power plan you use

3) Click "change advanced power settings" on the following screen

4) Expand the "Power buttons and lid" category, then expand the "power button action" category

5) In the drop down menu, change the setting to "Turn off the display"

Comment: I didn't know that was an option! I’ll look for that shortly…thanks.

Comment: @JDługosz any luck?